# sed: using part of the regular expression to parse the text

Tags: regex, sed

I have a line of text which looks like this:

```
/src/my_module_my_branch/my_module
```

Example: `/src/goodcode_dev/goodcode`

and I need to convert it to:

```
/src/my_branch/my_module
```

Example: `/src/dev/goodcode`

The problem both module and branch can include underscores.
So I need first to identify the module from the third part and use it to extract out the branch name.
Is there a way using sed to do such conversions?

Comment: I'm assuming you have more than one module. If that's the case, and they don't have a common naming structure (like a fixed number of `_` in them), I don't see how you could implement that without having one regex per module (or an alternation with them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, this should work. It assumes everything begins with `/src/`.

```
sed -r 's/^\/src\/([^/]+)_([^/]+)\/\1$/\/src\/\2\/\1/'
```

In English:

Invoke `sed` with extended regex (`-r`) so that `+` will work. Match beginning of line, `/src/`, group 1: one or more non-slashes, `_`, group 2: one or more non-slashes, `/`, group 1, end of line. Change to `/src/`, group 2, `/`, group 1.

Comment: +1, somewhat baffled that other replies seem to be written by people who are unfamiliar with regex backreferences.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for! I wasn't aware of the option of using the grouping clauses in the same expression. A very powerful feature.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the last part, then use it to substitute

```
$ echo "/src/my_module_my_branch/my_module" | awk -F"/" '{n=$NF;gsub(n"_","",$3);print}' OFS="/"
/src/my_branch/my_module
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any difference between the "module" and "branch" parts, then I'd say no. That is, if `my_module_my` could be the module, and `branch` the branch, then how would `sed` know?

Comment: Of course, if you could retrieve the module or branch name before running `sed`, it is trivial, but I assume that is not the case?

Comment: Since I'm replacing the text on some pipes I need to do it at once (or write an awk script which can do few actions in one iteration)